# How to change the theme of the presentation in google slide api?

Tags: reactjs, google-developers-console, google-slides-api

I can't change the theme of the presentation using the google slide api in a react application. How to change the theme when creating the presentation. Thank you for your help.

`

```
function createPresentation(title: string, callback: any) {
    try {
      gapi.client.slides.presentations
        .create({
          title: title,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(
            `Created presentation with ID: ${response.result.presentationId}`
          );
          console.log(response.result.masters);
          createSlide(
            response.result.presentationId,
            response.result.presentationId + "index",
            function (res: any) {
              window.open(              `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${response.result.presentationId}/edit#slide=id.p`,
                "_blank"
              );
              // console.log("response creation slide:", res);
            }
          );
          updatePresentationTheme(
            response.result.presentationId,
            response.result.masters && response.result.masters[0].objectId
          );

          if (callback) callback(response);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("errorrrrr:", err);
      return;
    }
  }`
```